# Is it fair to assume that using QueryLocatorIterator can reduce chance of heap size issues with Selectors?

Tags: apex, soql, query

With the Winter'23 release [removal of Open Cursor Limits](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_OpenCursorLimits.htm&type=5&release=240) I wonder, is it worth considering allowing returning `Database.QueryLocatorIterator` instead of `List<SObject>`?

I have made a quick-n-dirty sample of Selector:

```
public class AccountSelector {
    public static Database.QueryLocatorIterator queryById(Set<Id> ids) {
        String generatedSoql = 'SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id = :ids';
        Database.QueryLocator ql = Database.getQueryLocator(generatedSoql);
        return ql.iterator();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Database.QueryLocatorIterator ql = AccountSelector.queryById(new Set<Id>{'001...'});
while(ql.hasNext()){
    Account acct = (Account) ql.next();
    System.debug('Account found: ' + acct.Id);
}
```

The main drawbacks I see are:

- Iterators are not supported in for-loops, ugh!
- Their usage requires cast to the object.

With the benefit of:

- Potential reduction of heap size issues.
- Still allowing to keep queries together.

Comment: Heap size issues should _mostly_ only affect you when generating large csv files, or massive JSON payloads to send to external systems. Switching to query locators would be unlikely to provide much relief in those scenarios. Curious where you are seeing them.

Comment: Fair enough Adrian, my usual concern is on usage of lists with large SObjects. So potential benefits there but not much given iterators are not supported by for-loops yet.

Comment: to avoid casting in the "Usage:, have the selector return `Iterable<Account>` as database.QueryLocator can be cast to Iterable